# ajax jquery and click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have several buttons that have the same class 'unfollow'.
When the user clicks on one of the buttons it's triggering ajax request and changing the class to 'follow', and adding a click listener to the class.
When the user clicks on the 'follow' button it's triggering a new ajax request and changing the class to 'unfollow'.
Now the result is when the user clicks on the 'unfollow' link everything goes well, but when the user clicks on the 'follow' button it's triggering 2 ajax requests, 1 of the 'unfollow' and 1 of the 'follow'.

## Resolved

The new code:
**the promises simulate the ajax requests**

```
$('.btn').click(function(event) {
  var $self = $(this);
  var screenName = $self.parent().prev().children().children('p').text().substring(1);

  if ($self.hasClass('unfollow')) {
    var unfollowReq = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      $self.removeClass('unfollow').addClass('follow');
      $self.text('Follow');
      console.log('Unfollow');
      resolve();
    });
  } else if ($self.hasClass('follow')){
    var unfollowReq = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      $self.removeClass('follow').addClass('unfollow');
      $self.text('Unfollow');
      console.log('Follow');
      resolve();
    });
  }
});
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Liad91/zy8z872a/3)
Regards,
Liad.

Comment: Even if you change the class, the event handler doesn't go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the follow event listener after the follow click.

Use unbind() for this.

https://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Same thing happens when unfollow button click. Remove unfollow event listener and add follow event listener after the unfollow button click.

Comment: Thanks! I added the unbind() to the code and now it sends one request, but after the second unbind() I didn't succeed to bind it to the 'unfollow' again.. can you check the code? https://jsfiddle.net/Liad91/zy8z872a/2/

Comment: Follow and unfollow same hyperlink. I think you can use only one click listener and using class name, you call correct methods. So yo don't need to unbind. Use if($(this).hasClass( method on click listener.

Answer (score 0):

this is a way to toggle them using `data-...`

```
<button type="button" data-id="$id" data-action="follow" class="btn btn-primary btn-request">Follow</button>

$('.btn-request').click(function(e){
  var btn = $(this);
  var id = btn.data('id');
  var action = btn.data('action').toLowerCase();
  $(url, { id: id, action: (action == "follow" ? "unfollow" : "follow") }, funciton(result) {
      btn.data('action', (action == "follow" ? "Unfollow" : "Follow"));
      btn.html(btn.data('action'));
  });
});
```

or you can use `off()` or `unbind()` functions

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, event delegation is your best friend.

You can permanently delegate the two behaviours, follow and unfollow, to containing element(s). Thus, the buttons' behaviour, like their appearance, can be determined solely by the presence/absence of classNames - "follow" or "unfollow" in this case. There's no need to attach/detach event handlers.

jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) provides all the necessary fnctionality.

```
$(document).on('click', '.unfollow', function(event) {
    $self = $(this).removeClass('unfollow');
    // At this point, with neither class, 'follow' nor 'unfollow', the button is effectively disabled.
    $ajax(...).then(function() {
        // With assurance that the server-side state is at "unfollow", give the button "follow" appearance and behaviour.
        $self.addClass('follow').text('Follow');
    }, function(err) {
        // Hmm state is indeterminate.
        // Probably safer to assume that the ajax failed completely, therefore revert to "unfollow".
        $self.addClass('unfollow').text('Unfollow');
    });
}).on('click', '.follow', function() {
    $self = $(this).removeClass('follow');
    // At this point, with neither class, 'follow' nor 'unfollow', the button is effectively disabled.
    $ajax(...).then(function() {
        // With assurance that the server-side state is at "follow", give the button "unfollow" appearance and behaviour.
        $self.addClass('unfollow').text('Unfollow');
    }, function(err) {
        // Hmm state is indeterminate.
        // Probably safer to assume that the ajax failed completely, therefore revert to "follow".
        $self.addClass('follow').text('Follow');
    });
});
```

In practice, you would probably delegate to something other than `document`.

Promises appear to be completely irrelevant and are omitted.